# A simple QoS implementation with Cisco WRT160N

Tags: cisco, wifi, qos

We have a Cisco WRT160N wireless router which shares internet to ~5 clients. What I want to do is to make sure that every client has equal bandwidth.

The router has QoS option, but it gives priority to MAC adresses (or applications etc.) rather than an exact value. My question is, if I set MAC of every user and give equal priority to them, does it make sure that every connected client has the same bandwidth and nobody will block any other?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It will give each client the same priority which makes all traffic the same priority. QOS works by assuring higher priority traffic makes it out over lower priority traffic. It doesn't give equal amounts of bandwidth to each client. So what you should do is decide what traffic is important to you and prioritize that. Typically, you'll want to prioritize voice, http, and https and let all other traffic through only if there's enough bandwidth.